# How to add hamburger menu & functionality in React for mobile view?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm working on a React project and I'm trying to make my header section more mobile-responsive. Currently, I have three links (Home, About, and Login) in the left section, a centered logo/title, and search and cart buttons on the right side.

I want to add a hamburger icon that appears on mobile devices (when the screen width is less than 768px) that will toggle a menu containing the Home, About, and Login links. However, I want to keep the search and cart buttons outside of this hamburger menu, and maintain their position on the right side of the header.and I want to add the functionality code for the hamburger part

Here's my current code for the Header component (including the relevant styles):

`Header.jsx`

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import { TbSearch } from "react-icons/tb";
import { CgShoppingCart } from "react-icons/cg";

import Search from "./Search/Search";
import Cart from "../Cart/Cart";
import { Context } from "../../utils/context";

import "./Header.scss";

const Header = () => {

    const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);
    const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
    const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);
    const { cartCount } = useContext(Context);
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const handleScroll = () => {
        const offset = window.scrollY;
        if (offset > 200) {
            setScrolled(true);
        }
        else {
            setScrolled(false)
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <header className={`main-header ${scrolled ? 'sticky-header' : ''}`}>
                <div className="header-content">
                    <ul className="left">
                        <li onClick={() => navigate("/")}>Home</li>
                        <li onClick={() => navigate("/about")}>About</li>
                        <li onClick={() => navigate("/login")}>Login</li>
                    </ul>

                    <div className="center" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>GOLOC.</div>

                    <div className="right">
                        <TbSearch onClick={() => setShowSearch(true)} />

                        <span className="cart-icon" onClick={() => setShowCart(true)}>
                            <CgShoppingCart />
                            {!!cartCount && <span>{cartCount}</span>}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            {showCart && <Cart setShowCart={setShowCart} />}
            {showSearch && <Search setShowSearch={setShowSearch} />}
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

`Header.scss`

```
@import "../../css-config/mixins.scss";

.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 99;

    @include md {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }

    .header-content {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        @include md {
            height: 80px;
        }

        .left {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: none;
            gap: 25px;

            @include md {
                display: flex;
            }

            li {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: 600;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                cursor: pointer;

                @include sm {
                    // visibility: hidden;
                }
            }
        }

        .center {
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 700;
            cursor:
```

I've tried looking up solutions online and have experimented with various CSS properties and React libraries (such as react-icons), but I can't seem to get the desired result. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

This is Github repository of this project: https://github.com/aditya9-2/GOLOC

Answer (score 0):

My go to is to make a button with a hamburger icon, which gets only show on mobile view, so you can use media query for that. Also hide those three buttons in mobile view.

```
.hamburger{
   display:none; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
   .hamburger{
       display: block or inline-block
   }
   .left{
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Then you can use an onlick function to show left and add some css to make it flex columnwise, so it looks stacked

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS media query "@media screen and (max-width: your-breakpoint>)" to make your menu disappear on small screens. You can also use the React "useState" hook to toggle the button and change the show/hide class for your menu.

Here's how you can do it:

`Header.jsx`

```
     const [showMobileMenu , setShowMobileMenu ] = useState(false);


      <header className={`main-header ${scrolled ? "sticky-header" : ""}`}>
        <div className="header-content">
          <ul className={`left ${showMobileMenu ? 'show-mobile-menu':''}`}>
            <li onClick={() => navigate("/")}>Home</li>
            <li onClick={() => navigate("/about")}>About</li>
            <li onClick={() => navigate("/login")}>Login</li>
          </ul>

          <div className="center" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
            GOLOC.
          </div>

          <div className="right">
            <TbSearch onClick={() => setShowSearch(true)} />

            <span className="cart-icon" onClick={() => setShowCart(true)}>
              <CgShoppingCart />
              {!!cartCount && <span>{cartCount}</span>}
            </span>

            <button type="button" className="mobile-toggler" onClick={()=> setShowMobileMenu(!showMobileMenu)}>hamburger button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```

`Header.scss`

```
.mobile-toggler { display: none; } // default hide hamburger button

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .mobile-toggler { 
    display: block; 
    // style your hamburger button
   }

  .left {
// this will hide menu for small screen
// you can use display:none/block as you desired
    visibility: hidden; 

// these are optional you can add your style here
    width: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    transition: 400ms ease;
  }

// This will handle show/hide after you toggle your hamburger button
  .left.show-mobile-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The hamburger functionality is not working. and the scss properties also not working as I wanted check this :
 ` const [showMobileMenu, setShowMobileMenu] = useState(false); `
```
<ul className={`left ${showMobileMenu ? 'show-mobile-menu' : ''}`}>
                        <li onClick={() => navigate("/")}>Home</li>
                        <li onClick={() => navigate("/about")}>About</li>
                        <li onClick={() => navigate("/login")}>Login</li>
                    </ul>
GiHamburgerMenu className="mobile-toggler" onClick={() => setShowMobileMenu(!!showMobileMenu)} />
```

Comment: My bad for posting the wrong state update code implementation, could please try updating the hamburger click function code?
I have updated above code as well.

// This
`onClick={() => setShowMobileMenu(!!showMobileMenu)}`

// To this
`onClick={() => setShowMobileMenu(!showMobileMenu)}`

Comment: can you please provide me the SCSS code because it is not understandable for me and the code you provided is clashing with my existing code I might have use this code in wrong way can you provide me the full code for the left side and for the hamburger also?

Comment: and also i want the hamburger if the screen is for tablet and mobile and for desktop the home, about and login button will remain same in the left side of the header but for the mobile and tablet screen i want the hamburger and iside the hambrger i want the home, about and login button.

Comment: you can contribute to the github using creating another branch. the repository is public `https://github.com/aditya9-2/GOLOC/tree/master/client/src/components/Header`

Comment: You probably forgot to remove `display:none` from the `.left` class I have made the change to your repo in this branch `fix/responsive-header` have a look and do accept the answer if it worked for you.